# sentiment classification model- RNN and LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, sentiment-analysis, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train RNN with LSTM units for sentiment classification. 
I have labeled dataset with 0 for neg and 1 for pos.
my graph looks something like this:

```
input= tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, max_length], name='input')
se_len=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='lengths')
target= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes], name='target')
drop_keep_prob= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='dropout_keep_prob')

embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1, 
          1, seed=seed), name='embed_var')
embedded_words = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x) 

outputs = embedded_words  # [batch_size, max_length, embedding_size]
for h in hidden_size:
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, 
    input_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob,output_keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob, 
    seed=seed)
    outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, outputs, dtype=tf.float32, 
        sequence_length=seq_len)


outputs = tf.reduce_mean(outputs, reduction_indices=[1])
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_size[-1], n_classes], seed=random_state)) 

b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[n_classes]))
scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(outputs, w, b, name='scores')  ##[batch_size, n_classes]

predict = tf.nn.softmax(scores, name='predictions')

losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=scores, 
 labels=target, name='cross_entropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses, name='loss')
# train_ step=rmsoptimize().minimize(loss)

## cores / predict
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(scores, 1), tf.argmax(target, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
```

if I want to classify only one sentence..and use the model, I'm not sure how to do that... what I tried so far is to create index vector (according to my lexicon) with the size of the maximum sequence length and feed it to the model like this:

```
def predict(tensor):
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        sess = tf.Session()
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}/model.ckpt.meta".format(FLAGS.checkpoints_dir))
        saver.restore(sess, ("{}/model.ckpt".format(FLAGS.checkpoints_dir)))

        input = graph.get_operation_by_name('input').outputs[0]
        seq_len = graph.get_operation_by_name('lengths').outputs[0]
        dropout_keep_prob = graph.get_operation_by_name('dropout_keep_prob').outputs[0]
        prediction = graph.get_operation_by_name('final_layer/softmax/predictions').outputs[0]

score = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={input: tensor.reshape(1,convector.sequence_len), seq_len:[convector.sequence_len],dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('Predicted sentiment: [{0:.4f}, {1:.4f}]'.format(score[0, 0], score[0, 1]))
            return score
```

am I doing something wrong? 
how can I know how to choose hyperparameters so that it could coop with cases like underfitting or overfitting  ??

Comment: "How can I know how to choose hyperparameters so that it could coop with cases like underfitting or overfitting" - you should try many different hyperparameters and pick the best you find.

Comment: ok ..but what about the classification task? is this the way to do this in a single sentence?